# Preventing convertion of ASCII rules on org--html export

Tags: org-export

When you export to html, `--` is converted to en-rule and `---` to em-rule.  Is it possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These conversions are defined by a set of regular expressions in file `ox-export.el`:

```el
(defconst org-html-special-string-regexps
  '(("\\\\-" . "&#x00ad;")      ; shy
    ("---\\([^-]\\)" . "&#x2014;\\1")   ; mdash
    ("--\\([^-]\\)" . "&#x2013;\\1")    ; ndash
    ("\\.\\.\\." . "&#x2026;"))     ; hellip
  "Regular expressions for special string conversion.")
```

So you could change them by redefining this value, **after** `ox-export` has been loaded (as `defconst` unconditionnaly sets the value).   A possible way would be to add the following to your init file:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ox-html
  '(setq org-html-special-string-regexps
    '(("\\\\-" . "&#x00ad;")        ; shy
      ("---\\([^-]\\)" . "---\\1")  ; mdash
      ("--\\([^-]\\)" . "--\\1")    ; ndash
      ("\\.\\.\\." . "&#x2026;"))   ; hellip
    ))
```

That is, after `ox-export` has been loaded (and the variable set), we change its value.